# What's the npm command that fills in dependency version numbers?

Tags: node.js, npm

I know there's a quick way to fill in my package.json with version numbers instead of asterisks. I'm pretty sure it's just an npm command, but I can't find it.

Any help would rock!

Comment: [`shrinkwrap`](https://npmjs.org/doc/shrinkwrap.html)?

Comment: Hmmm... cool, that creates a file that locks down version numbers. I was hoping it would just edit my package.json file. Thanks though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had a similar problem. And wrote a little npm-utility for this problem.

```
npm install -g npm-stiv
```

go to your project directory and run

```
npm-stiv
```

It create backpup package.json file, named bck_package.json and fill asterisks according installed deps version numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The `--save` command will add version numbers to package.json

```
npm install <module> --save
```

I believe it will use the major version and not upgrade beyond it.

Comment: Strange, it didn't work for me. I just got the no readme warning for my package, that's not required is it?

Comment: Now check you package.json file. It should have version numbers for the module you added.

Comment: Try npm remove and `npm install <module> --save` again. Not sure why you're not seeing version numbers.

Comment: You probably already had them installed previously. `--save` only works for new modules.

Comment: What if we don't want to upgrade the module?

Comment: then use `1.2.1` for example instead of `^1.2`